# Rebuild old Perl Modules

Tags: arch-linux, perl

I just did a system update on Arch Linux (`pacman -Syu`) and saw a warning about there being old Perl modules:

```
WARNING: '/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl' contains data from at least 2 packages which will NOT be used by the installed perl interpreter.
 -> Run the following command to get a list of affected packages: pacman -Qqo '/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl'
WARNING: '/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl' contains data from at least 8 packages which will NOT be used by the installed perl interpreter.
 -> Run the following command to get a list of affected packages: pacman -Qqo '/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl'
```

Running the recommended commands yielded the following:

```
$ pacman -Qqo '/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl'
gscan2pdf
perl-filesys-df
$ pacman -Qqo '/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl'
perl-config-general
perl-data-uuid
perl-goo-canvas
perl-gtk2-ex-simple-list
perl-gtk2-imageview
perl-pdf-api2
perl-sane
perl-set-intspan
```

I encountered something similar once before when the version of Perl was updated. If I recall correctly those Perl packages needed to be rebuilt; however, I do not remember where I found the incantation to do this. Please note that I have absolutely no experience with Perl. Those modules are simply used by *gscan2pdf* which I installed through AUR. How do I rebuild these Perl modules?

Comment: You reinstall them from the AUR, and hope that the maintainer has updated the PKGBUILDs to conform to the new library path.

Comment: Please do not pass two `y` options to `pacman -S`, as this *fully rebuilds* your sync database unconditionally, rather than simply retrieving deltas. `-Syy` is only necessary when your sync database has become corrupt somehow. Doing this regularly provides no additional benefit and merely wastes bandwidth for both you and the mirror you're using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To rebuild the `perl` libraries from `AUR` for `pacmanager` I use **yaourt**:

```
yaourt -S --asdeps perl-gnome2-gconf glade-perl perl-crypt-blowfish perl-gnome2-vte perl-expect perl-crypt-rijndael perl-gtk2-ex-simple-list perl-io-stty perl-io-tty perl-net-arp perl-yaml perl-crypt-cbc perl-gtk2-unique perl-socket6 uuid
```

so just replace the libraries with the ones `pacman` gave you:

```
yaourt -S --asdeps gscan2pdf perl-filesys-df perl-config-general perl-data-uuid perl-goo-canvas perl-gtk2-ex-simple-list perl-gtk2-imageview perl-pdf-api2 perl-sane perl-set-intspan
```

**Update 2018 additional**

the `perl 5.28` update in Arch means that you have to rebuild all unsupported packages again. The solution to fix dependency errors is to **remove** the offending **AUR** `perl` application & then remove the orphan `perl` libraries & update your system:

```
sudo pacman -Rns $(pacman -Qtdq)
sudo pacman -Syu
```

Finally reinstall the **AUR** `perl` application.

**Update 2019 additional**

With the `perl 5.30.0` update `pacman` now gives warnings about old `perl` libs. This time I had a big update & needed to do the following:

```
sudo pacman -R $conflicting_perl_mod_&_app
sudo pacman -Syu
# pacman now generates a warning for unused perl libs
pacman -R $(pacman -Qqo '/usr/lib/perl5/5.28')
pacman -S $perl_app
# optional remove orphaned packages
sudo pacman -Rns $(pacman -Qtdq)
sudo pacman -Syu
```

Comment: I use `pacaur`, but the solution is the same: reinstall the packages.

Comment: The updated information you provided is inaccurate. `pacman -Rns $(pacman -Qtdq)` will remove **all** orphaned packages on the system, not just orphaned perl library packages.

Answer (score 2):

Adding onto Stuart Cardall's answer, make a .sh script to rebuild the listed perl modules, then you can just run that whenever you update perl and get that warning:

```
#!/bin/bash    
yaourt -S --asdeps --noconfirm $(pacman -Qqo '/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl')
yaourt -S --asdeps --noconfirm $(pacman -Qqo '/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl')
```